# How can I write ftp command for a file transfer from one server to other?

Tags: ftp

How can I write ftp command for a file transfer from one server to other with a simple script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894347/how-to-upload-ftp-files-to-server-in-a-bash-script

Comment: You mean transferring files directly between server1 and server2 while controlling the transfer from client3?

Comment: No, to transfer files from server-1 to server-2, while controlling from server-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lftp (and a lot of other ftp clients) will let you specify username, password, and the series of commands to issue with its command line. **man lftp** for more details.